Finding the gradient of a scalar function with vector function input
I'm studying for my qualifying exam, and the study materials have no solutions/guides. One problem that's killing me is as follows:
Let $\vec{f}: R^3 \rightarrow R^2$:
$$\vec{f}(x,y,z)=(f_1(x,y,z),f_2(x,y,z))$$
And let $g: R^2 \rightarrow R$ be a differentiable function such that $g(1,0) = -1$ and $\nabla g(1,0) = (-1,3)$. Compute the gradient of $g(\vec{f}(\vec{x}))$ at the point $\vec{x}=(0,0,0)$.
The components of $\vec{f}$ are given in the problem but not typed out here for the sake of brevity.
I'm assuming this is some kind of chain rule problem, but I can't find any examples in my textbooks/online with this kind of structure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Have you tried just using the chain rule and setting $x = (0,0,0)$?

What's confusing me is what the chain rule would look like in this situation. The gradient is $\nabla g = (\frac{\delta g}{\delta f_1},\frac{\delta g}{\delta f_2})$, but how do I get those partials?

You're given a value of $\nabla g$, so that you very likely don't need to find such a value.

Let $\mathbf{h}:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}, \quad\mathbf{h}=g\left(\mathbf{f}(x,y,z)\right)$ where $\mathbf{f}(x,y,z)=\left(f_1(x,y,z),f_2(x,y,z)\right)$
We want $\nabla\mathbf{h}(0,0,0)$.
For the chain rule, we have:
$$\nabla\mathbf{h}(x,y,z)=\nabla g\left(f_1(x,y,z),f_2(x,y,z)\right)\cdot J_{\mathbf{f}}(x,y,z)$$
where $$J_{\mathbf{f}}(x,y,z)=\begin{pmatrix}\partial_xf_1(x,y,z)  && \partial_yf_1(x,y,z) && \partial_z f_1(x,y,z) \\ \partial_xf_2(x,y,z)  && \partial_yf_2(x,y,z) && \partial_z f_2(x,y,z)  \end{pmatrix}$$
is the jacobian matrix of $\mathbf{f}$.
So, we have:
$$\nabla\mathbf{h}(0,0,0)=\nabla g\left(f_1(0,0,0),f_2(0,0,0)\right)\cdot J_{\mathbf{f}}(0,0,0)$$
and with the explicit components of $\mathbf{f}$ you can compute it.
